# When is ClassLoader checkPackageAccess method called

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, securitymanager, classloading

I would like to understand when the JVM calls the checkPackageAccess method of a ClassLoader. From the javadoc, I read that it is called by the JVM after loading class with the classloader. But I found out that sometimes it is called more than one time after a loadclass. On what basis does the JVM decide to call it. I would really appreciate it, if someone can clarify the method.

To make it easier to understand, here is what I did:

1. I run the same program twice. Both times with -noverify
2. In one run I remove the `<clinit>` from the classes, in the other run not.

The run with `<clinit>` looks like this: 
[Run with clinit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQT41.jpg)

The one without like this: 
[Run without clinit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUKhp.jpg)

So as you can see the run without clinit leads to three calls to `checkPackageAccess` after `java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo` was loaded while the normal run (with clinit) only leads to one. Since in both runs the `<clinit>` (neither the original one, not the empty one in the second run) is not yet exeuted I wonder what leads the JVM to perform this `checkPackageAccess` call.

- First `checkPackageAccess` is for `java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo` (in
  both runs)
- Second one is for `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`
- Third one is for `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue`

I use JVMTI methodEntry and methodExit events to generate a trace of everything that is happening. Nevertheless I can't explain what leads to those additional `checkPackageAccess` calls.

Comment: Please do not mix two questions into one. Are you asking when `checkPackageAccess` is called or why `ConcurrentHashMap` is loaded?

Comment: Yes you are right. Maybe it is mixed. The main question is about the checkPackageAccess. But I got the checkPackageAccess for ConcurrentHashMap and that is why I added the loading of the concurrenthashmap as well. I felt like it is related.

Comment: Oh also for additional information, I started it with -noverify.

Comment: @apangin I just updated the question to hopefully make it more clear and added to screenshots of some method traces that I am generating.